# moment.js check if system time format is 12 hours or 24 hours?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to get the current system setting time format if 12 hours or 24 hours?

`date.toLocaleTimeString` does not work always return time in 12 hours.

I need to display time on the basis of the system's time format.

example:

```
  let currentDateTime = new Date();
  console.log(currentDateTime.toLocaleTimeString())
```

result:

```
7:50:00 PM
```

I'm expecting `19:50:00` because my current system settings is 24hours format in my computer.
see image:
[image]

Comment: Can you give examples where `toLocaleTimeString` does not do what you want?

Comment: @trincot it always return 12 hours time format

Comment: Please, can you edit your question and clarify with examples?

Comment: @trincot updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: MomentJS is dead. Please do not use it if you can skip it. Also, please do not tags specific framework if your question is not related to them specifically.

Comment: All you can do is use locale format, which might not match the format the user has selected for their operating system.  JavaScript doesn't have that level of access.

Answer (score 0):

for 24 hours you can make 12 hours false like this:

```js
let currentDateTime = new Date();
console.log(currentDateTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false }))
```

Comment: It always returns 24 hours format. I'm expecting 24 and 12 hours time format based on the system settings of the device.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple approach using moment.js

```
function is12HourFormat(time: string): boolean {
    return moment(time, 'hh:mm', true).isValid();
}
```

For 24 hour format :

```
function is24HourFormat(time: string): boolean {
    return moment(time, 'HH:mm', true).isValid();
}
```

Comment: momentJS is not something to use anymore unfortunately, date-fns or alike is better and fully maintained.